# Не отображаются кнопки

Tags: java, swing

Говорю сразу, я полнейший новичок. У меня не отображаются кнопки ОК(settingsButtonOK) и Cancel(settingsButonCancel).

package gui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class File extends JComponent {

```
public static JFrame jSettings = getSettings();

private static JButton settingsButtonOK = new JButton("OK");
private static JButton settingsButtonCancel = new JButton("Cancel");

public static JFrame getSettings() {

    jSettings = new JFrame("Settings");
    jSettings.setSize(400, 400);
    jSettings.add(new File());
    jSettings.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jSettings.setResizable(false);
    jSettings.setVisible(true);

    JPanel radioButtonsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    JRadioButton styleButton1 = new JRadioButton("1");
    JRadioButton styleButton2 = new JRadioButton("2");
    radioButtonsPanel.add(styleButton1);
    radioButtonsPanel.add(styleButton2);
    jSettings.add(radioButtonsPanel);
    styleButton1.setSelected(true);

    settingsButtonOK.setBounds(220, 350, 80, 40);
    jSettings.add(settingsButtonOK);

    settingsButtonCancel.setBounds(310, 350, 80, 40);
    jSettings.add(settingsButtonCancel);

    jSettings.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    //Жесткий костыль, нужно исправить
    jSettings.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.ERROR);

    return jSettings;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

jSettings.getContentPane().add(settingsButtonOK);
jSettings.getContentPane().add(settingsButtonCancel);

Так будут отображаться кнопки

А лучше создать панель для кнопок:

```
JPanel settingsButtonsPanel = new JPanel();

jSettings.add(radioButtonsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
jSettings.add(settingsButtonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```